# How to show content when click on button

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a button that I would like when the user clicks on it to show what is inside my MaterialTextField. Inside my materialtextfield's there is: value={projectFilter.eventName}, {projectFilter.eventYear}, and others that follow the same logic. How can I make it so that I have this result?

UPDATE(here some example of what I want to show when I click the button):

```
return (
<Grid item xs={4}>

            <MaterialTextField

              autoComplete="off"
              variant="outlined"
              label="Name"
              type="text"
              name="eventName"
              value={projectFilter.eventName}
              sx={{ width: '100%' }}
            />
          </Grid>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide some code sample.

Basically you have to set state which will change when user clicks the button.

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 0):

You need state to store the current value of the field. You can use the `useState` hook for this. You should really read through the React documentation. The `useState` [hook docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) in particular is what you are after but it will make much more sense if you read state and lifecycle and just understand how react works.

Here is an example assuming that this `projectFilter` object is passed into the component as a prop.

```
import React from 'react';

export const SomeComponent = ({ projectFilter }) => {
    const [fieldValue, setFieldValue] = React.useState('');

    const clickHandler = (e) => {
        // Set the value of the state here. This will cause a re-render.
        setFieldValue(projectFilter.eventName);
    };

    return (
        <Grid item xs={4}>
            <MaterialTextField value={fieldValue} />
            <button onClick={clickHandler}>Click this</button>
        </Grid>
    );
```

Comment: My projectFilter is passed in to the component as a prop. But when I did as you told my export const SomeComponent is sayin':  Modifiers cannot appear here.
And in the onCLick is sayin: Cannot find the name 'clickHandler'. and the same happens in the value={fieldValue}